# Additional information with widgets in django

Tags: django, forms, layout, widget

I am displaying a django widget, with which I need to display additional information (something like a tool tip) that is attendant to the widget.  I essentially have a widget that asks a random question, which is self contained.

```
{{ form.fieldname }}
```

displays the full widget which looks something like (à la the widget's render method):

```
<label for="id_answer">Question:</label>
<input type="hidden" name="question_id" value="n" />
<span class="prompt">What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?</span>
<input type="text" name="answer" />
```

What I'm essentially asking is, is there a way to break out the prompt, so that I can lay the widget out piecemeal?  I would like to lay it out not with a call to {{ form.fieldname }} as above, but like:

```
{{ form.fieldname.label }}
{{ form.fieldname.prompt }}
{{ form.fieldname }}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[Something like this?](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template)

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to do as rebus suggests, except with the caveat of an additional attribute of field which would be field.prompt (or arbitrarily named).

Something like this:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.a_custom_method }} // called "prompt" in the op
        {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
<p><input type="submit" value="Send message" /></p>
```